# Java Bytecode instrumentation with ASM: VerifyError on code injection at INVOKESPECIAL instructions

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents, verifyerror

I'm quite new in bytecode injection. Until now, I was able to get everything what I wanted by exhaustive research and painful trial and error :-) 
But I seem to have reached my limits with the currently pursued objective. So, here it is: my very first stackoverflow question!

My aim is to trace the object references of method invocations via a java agent. I am using the ASM 4.0 library and have implemented an AdviceAdapter.
My overriden visitMethodInsn()-method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Visits a method instruction. A method instruction is an instruction that invokes a method.
 * The stack before INVOKEINTERFACE, INVOKESPECIAL and INVOKEVIRTUAL instructions is:
 * "objectref, [arg1, arg2, ...]"
 *
 * @param opcode the opcode of the type instruction to be visited. This opcode is either INVOKEVIRTUAL, INVOKESPECIAL, INVOKESTATIC or INVOKEINTERFACE.
 * @param owner  the internal name of the method's owner class.
 * @param name   the method's name.
 * @param desc   the method's descriptor.
 */
@Override
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {
    if (isExcluded()) {
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        return;
    }

    int arraySlot = -1;
    boolean isStatic = false;
    if (opcode == INVOKEVIRTUAL || opcode == INVOKEINTERFACE) {
        arraySlot = saveMethodParameters(owner, desc);
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
    } else if (opcode == INVOKESTATIC) {
        isStatic = true;
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
    } else if (opcode == INVOKESPECIAL && !owner.equals("java/lang/Object")) {
        //TODO: Causes VerifyError
        arraySlot = saveMethodParameters(owner, desc);
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
    } else {
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
    }

    if (arraySlot > 0) {
        loadLocal(arraySlot);
        push(0);
        arrayLoad(Type.getType(Object.class));
    } else {
        super.visitInsn(ACONST_NULL);
    }
    super.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "net/myjavaagent/MethodLogger",
            "writeToLoggerTest", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V");
}

 /**
 * Pops the method invocation' arguments and objectref off the stack, saves them into a local array variable and
 * then puts them back on the stack again.
 *
 * @param owner owner class of the method
 * @param desc  method descriptor
 * @return the identifier of the local variable containing the parameters.
 */
private int saveMethodParameters(String owner, String desc) {
    JavaTracerAgent.agentErrorLogger.info("Save method parameters: " + owner + " " + desc);
    // Preparing the array construction
    Type objectType = Type.getType(Object.class);
    Type objectArrayType = Type.getType("[Ljava/lang/Object;");
    Type[] invokeParamTypes = getMethodParamTypes(owner, desc);
    int invokeParamCount = invokeParamTypes.length;

    // allocate a slot for the method parameters array
    int arrayLocal = newLocal(objectArrayType);
    // construct the object array
    push(invokeParamCount);
    newArray(objectType);
    // store array in the local variable
    storeLocal(arrayLocal);

    // pop the arguments off the stack into the array
    // note: the top one is the last parameter !
    for (int i = invokeParamCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Type type = invokeParamTypes[i];
        JavaTracerAgent.agentErrorLogger.info("Get from stack [" + i + "]:" + type.toString());

        if (type != null) {
            // convert value to object if needed
            box(type);
            // load array and  swap under value
            loadLocal(arrayLocal);
            swap(objectArrayType, objectType);
            // load index and swap under value
            push(i);
            swap(Type.INT_TYPE, objectType);
        } else {
            // this is a static method and index is 0 so we put null into the array
            // load array index and then null
            loadLocal(arrayLocal);
            push(i);
            push((Type) null);
        }
        // store the value in the array as an object
        arrayStore(objectType);
    }

    // now restore the stack and put back the arguments from the array in increasing order
    for (int i = 0; i < invokeParamCount; i++) {
        Type type = invokeParamTypes[i];
        JavaTracerAgent.agentErrorLogger.info("Put to stack [" + i + "]:" + type.toString());

        if (type != null) {
            // load the array
            loadLocal(arrayLocal);
            //retrieve the object at index i
            push(i);
            arrayLoad(objectType);
            //unbox if needed
            unbox(type);
        } else {
            // this is a static method so no target instance has to be put on stack
        }
    }

    return arrayLocal;
}

/**
 * Returns a type array containing the parameters of a method invocation:
 * <ul><li>owner type</li><li>arg1 type</li><li>arg2 type</li><li>...</li><li>argN type</li></ul>
 *
 * @param owner owner class
 * @param desc  method descriptor
 * @return method parameter types
 */
public Type[] getMethodParamTypes(String owner, String desc) {
    Type ownerType = Type.getObjectType(owner);
    Type[] argTypes = Type.getArgumentTypes(desc);
    int numArgs = argTypes.length;
    Type[] result = new Type[numArgs + 1];
    result[0] = ownerType;
    System.arraycopy(argTypes, 0, result, 1, numArgs);

    return result;
}
```

In short, I am trying to save everything which is on the stack before the INVOKESOMETHING operation is executed into a local variable. 
In order to enable the execution of the method operation I have to put the whole stuff back to the stack. Afterwards I assume that the reference of the called object is the first entry in my local array.

In the following is one of my test classes. This one is pretty simple: it is just starting another thread:

```
/**
* My test class.
*/
public class ThreadStarter {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Thread thread = new Thread("Hugo") {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Concerning INVOKEVIRTUAL, INVOKEINTERFACE and INVOKESTATIC I did not face any issues. Everything seems fine and the logging output is exactly what I expect.
However, there seems to be a problem with the INVOKESPECIAL instruction. I'm facing an ugly VerifyError here so I guess there must be something wrong in the way that I treat the stack.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: net/petafuel/qualicore/examples/ThreadStarter, method: main signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V) Expecting to find object/array on stack
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
```

Starting the test class with the "-noverify" makes the VerifyError disappear. Everything seems to work just perfectly and I get the desired output. I could just leave it like that but actually the whole issue is causing me pain and lets me sleep very bad ;-)

If my understanding is correct, some statement like "new Thread()" turns to be

```
NEW java/lang/Thread
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL <init>
```

in bytecode. Could it be a problem that the newly created object is still uninitialzed before the constructor is invoked?

I do not understand why the code is working but the JVM is complaining during verification.

Even looking at the decompiled code after instrumentation does not help me:

```
// Decompiled by Jad v1.5.8g. Copyright 2001 Pavel Kouznetsov.
// Jad home page: http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html
// Decompiler options: packimports(3) 
// Source File Name:   ThreadStarter.java
public class ThreadStarter
{

    public ThreadStarter()
    {
        MethodLogger.writeToLoggerTest(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JVM INSTR new #2   <Class ThreadStarter$1>;
        JVM INSTR dup ;
        "Hugo";
        Object aobj[] = new Object[2];
        aobj;
        JVM INSTR swap ;
        1;
        JVM INSTR swap ;
        JVM INSTR aastore ;
        aobj;
        JVM INSTR swap ;
        0;
        JVM INSTR swap ;
        JVM INSTR aastore ;
        ((_cls1)aobj[0])._cls1((String)aobj[1]);
        MethodLogger.writeToLoggerTest(aobj[0]);
        Thread thread;
        thread;
        thread;
        Object aobj1[] = new Object[1];
        aobj1;
        JVM INSTR swap ;
        0;
        JVM INSTR swap ;
        JVM INSTR aastore ;
        ((Thread)aobj1[0]).start();
        MethodLogger.writeToLoggerTest(aobj1[0]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Some additional information:
I am developping with IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.4 and using jdk1.6.0_39.

Finally, I hope that somebody here can help me to get the necessary insight. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, there are some restrictions concerning passing around unititialized instances. (that is, objects which are created with "new", but where the constructor is not called yet) I guess this is causing your verification error. For more detailed verification output, try to use the verifier built into ASM. It gives way more information about the errors

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the tip to use the ASM verifier. Although I did not get any output at all for this issue using the ASM verifier, I will consider it for any upcoming problem I may face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks again to Mike and ruediste for their comments.

Mike was right: 
My problem was that I tried passing a reference as a method call argument right after it was created by NEW but before its constructor has been called. The JVM specification clearly states that such a behavior is forbidden: "The verifier rejects code that uses the new object before it has been initialized [...]" (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.4)

However, the instruction sequence of creating and initializing a new object leaves my desired object on top of the operand stack where it can easily be obtained :)

In the end, I blew up my code bit for the INVOKESPECIAL handling:

```
if (opcode == INVOKESPECIAL) {
    // Invoke constructors and private methods

    // Ignore initialization of java/lang/Object
    if (name.equals("<init>") && owner.equals("java/lang/Object")) {
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        return;
    }

    if (methodName.equals("<clinit>")) {

        if (name.equals("<clinit>")) {
            // call to a static initializer from within a static initializer
            // there is no object reference!
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        } else if (name.equals("<init>")) {
            // call to a constructor from within a static initializer
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
            // object reference is initialized and on stack now -> obtain it via DUP
        } else {
            // call to a private method from within a static initializer
            // no this-reference in static initializer!
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        }

    } else if (methodName.equals("<init>")) {

        if (name.equals("<clinit>")) {
            // call to a static initializer from within a constructor
            // there is no object reference!
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        } else if (name.equals("<init>")) {
            // call to a constructor from within a constructor
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
            // if this constructor call is not an invocation of the super constructor: obtain object reference via DUP
        } else {
            // call to a private method from within a constructor
            // object reference is the this-reference (at local variable 0)
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        }

    } else {

        if (name.equals("<clinit>")) {
            // call to a static initializer from within some method
            // there is no object reference!
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        } else if (name.equals("<init>")) {
            // call to a constructor from within some method
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
            // obtain object reference via DUP
        } else {
            // call to a private method from within some method
            // if the private method is called within some NON-STATIC method: object reference is the this-reference (at local variable 0)
            // if the private method is called within some NON-STATIC method: there is no object reference!
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
        }
    }
}
```

Possibly this helps someone who's trying to do similar stuff :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two causes I am aware of that might produce this error when `INVOKESPECIAL` is concerend:

1. You are attempting invoke a constructor on a reference that cannot be verified as uninitialized (the first argument to `INVOKESPECIAL` *must* be an uninitialized reference).
2. You are attempting to pass an uninitialized reference somewhere where an initialized reference is expected (as an argument to a method call, an AASTORE operation, etc.).

A cursory glance of your code suggests you may be storing an uninitialized reference in your method parameters array.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Reconsidering my code, I believe the reason for the VerifyError indeed is my attempt to store an uninitialized reference into a local array.